# How can I reduce redundant code of duplicate function in Golang?

Tags: function, go, struct, redundancy

I have a Rest API application to list all json data to browser. as long as I have more modules my code is more redundant. and complex.

```
func UserList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    list := []models.User{}
    db.Find(&list)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list)
}

func ProductList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    list := []models.Product{}
    db.Find(&list)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list)
}

func OrderList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    list := []models.Order{}
    db.Find(&list)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list)
}
```

Is there any better solution to make this code into just one function 
Example

```
func List(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    list := ??? List of struct here ???
    db.Find(&list)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list)
}
```

Comment: How would you decide in the unified `List()` function what type of `list` should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
func List(list interface{}, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request,) {
    db.Find(list)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the model type as a request param, this should do it (including error handling):

```
func List(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var list interface{}
    switch r.FormValue("model") {
    case "user":
        list = new([]models.User)
    case "product":
        list = new([]models.Product)
    case "order":
        list = new([]models.Order)
    default:
        http.Error(w, "invalid type", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    if err := db.Find(list); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "db error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list); err != nil {
        log.Printf("json encoding error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Another option is to build a registry of types, and even the slice creation can be factored out, using the help of `reflect`:

```
var reg = map[string]reflect.Type{
    "user":    reflect.TypeOf((*models.User)(nil)).Elem(),
    "product": reflect.TypeOf((*models.Product)(nil)).Elem(),
    "order":   reflect.TypeOf((*models.Order)(nil)).Elem(),
}

func List(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    etype := reg[r.FormValue("model")]
    if etype == nil {
        http.Error(w, "invalid type", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    list := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(etype)).Interface()
    if err := db.Find(list); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "db error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list); err != nil {
        log.Printf("json encoding error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second option is pretty good.
I'm currently using GORM and variable list accept only slice or struct. how can I change from interface to slice or struct?

Comment: @NightOwl Both my examples pass a pointer to slice to `db.Find()`, just like your examples in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure about that,
but when I ran my code it show result as normal. and when I try your code it show 
message "unsupported destination, should be slice or struct"
it might be something different between 
`list := []models.User{}
db.Find(&list)`
and
`list := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(etype)).Interface()
db.Find(list)`

Comment: @NightOwl See this playground example which proves they are the same: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ieWdKmV-Udk). Are you sure you copied my example properly? E.g. in my example you have to pass `list` to `db.Find()`, and not `&list`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are calling `db.Find(&list)` I assume that they share a common interface. In which case you could wrap your handler calls like so;

```
func ListHandler(list <YOUR_INTERFACE>) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        db.Find(&list)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list)
    }
}
```

In your call;

```
http.HandleFunc("/user/list", ListHandler([]models.User{}))
http.HandleFunc("/product/list", ListHandler([]models.Product{}))
http.HandleFunc("/order/list", ListHandler([]models.Order{}))
```